# Possible to have $m$-dimensional $C^k$ embedded submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^p$ with canonical projections onto $m$ dimensions are of dim $<m$ a.e.?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Notations/terminologies:**

Let $\lambda_m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Let $\sigma \in \Sigma_p$ be a permutation of the symbols $\{1,2...p\}$.
Let $k\mathbb{N}$ denote a desired degree of smoothness of the manifold in question.

Let $M^m \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ be a $C^k$ embedded submanifold of dimension $m$. Does this *always* mean that: at least one of the canonical projections onto a collection of  $m$ canonical (Euclidean) co-ordinates give rise to/have an image $N$, so that $N \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is also $\lambda_m$ almost everywhere a submanifold (with or without boundary) of $\mathbb{R}^p$ of dimension exactly $m$? I.e. is it true that, for any canonical projection $\pi: (x_1,...x_p) \mapsto (x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},...x_{\sigma(m)})$, where $\sigma \in \Sigma_p, N:=\pi(M)$ is also a $\lambda_m$ almost everywhere a submanifold?

**In other words, my question is:** is it possible to construct a submanifold $M^m \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ so that all of the ${p \choose m}$ canonical projections onto any of the $m$ co-ordinates have dimension strictly less than $m$ for a subset of positive $\lambda_m$ measure?

**Attemp I:** The way I was thinking of constructing a counter example is by constructing a non-linear map from a low dimension to a high dimension so that there's enough co-ordinates to make the map invertible, but none of the low dimensional projections are invertible. E.g. I was thinking of constructing a map:

$F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by: $F(x,y):=(xy^2, x^2y, xy + x^2y)$ so that we can check that projection onto any of the two co-ordinates have manifold dimension $1$. But I'm not sure if it's possible to construct such a counterexample?

**Attemp II:** I think for any smooth submanifold in question defined using global charts (like the ones I was trying in **Attempt I**) wouldn't give us a counter example. This is because, locally, any smooth submanifold of dimension $m$ can be written as $F(x_1,...x_m)\mapsto (y_1,...y_p)$ where $y_i = y_i(x_1,...x_m)$ is a smooth function so that the Jacobian $[\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}]_{1 \leq i \le m, 1 \leq j \leq p }$ is of rank $m$, hence an $m \times m$ submatrix, which WLOG can be assumed to be $[\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}]_{1 \leq i \le m, 1 \leq j \leq m }$ is of full rank $m$. But then the projection $(y_1,...y_m, y_{m+1},...y_p) \mapsto (y_1,...y_m)$ gives us locally a manifold of dimension $m$. **But I guess we can't construct a global such projection?**

Comment: Is your submanifold smooth? If so, use the submersion theorem or implicit function theorem. Keep in mind that it's possible that none of the projections is a submanifold.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes we can assume smoothness, but are you saying even then it's possible that none of the projections is a submanifold? If so, could you be a bit more precise and write what the conclusion is or write a counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: @MoisheKohan Also, even if the projections are not submanifolds, is it possible that they're only a measure zero set of singilar points? If this is the case, this ins't of a great interest to me; but ideally I'm interested to see if the projections have a positive measure of points whose neighborhoods have dimensions $<m=$ dim of the priginal submanifold.

Comment: The simplest example is the unit circle in the plane: Its projections to both coordinate lines are not submanifolds. As for the measure of the singular set (in general), yes, it is measure zero. Do you know Sard's Theorem?

Comment: I suggest, you edit your question: Your are actually asking two different questions (three if you count the question about measure asked in your comment): One is about existence of a projection which is a submanifold of dimension $m$, the other is about existence of a projection which has dimension $m$ (this is defined for arbitrary subsets, not necessarily manifolds). These questions have opposite answers.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'll shortly edit it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry for the delay, I've edited the question and formulated in exactly the way I want it. Hopefully this'll make more sense this time.

Comment: I guess "smooth" means $C^\infty$, which is the standard way to interpret smoothness, otherwise you should clarify. Then, the revised question has positive answer. This is a consequence of the implicit function theorem and Sard's theorem. I will write an answer once I have time.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, I edited the part about smooth. So are you saying that for every $m$ dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^p$, so that one of its $m$-dimensional projections will map it onto a subset which is almost everywhere an $m$-dimensional manifold. Or are you saying that this is not the case? Thanks, and loking forward to your answer!

Comment: Yes,  the projection is a.e. a smooth $m$-dimensional submanifold, i.e. the interior of the image has full measure in the closure.

Comment: Did you understand the proof?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that $M$ is nonempty (by the definition, the empty set is a manifold of every dimension $m$). I also assume that you want a projection $\pi$ to some coordinate subspace $R^m$ of dimension $m$ such that $\pi(M)$ has **nonempty interior** and topological boundary (frontier) of zero measure.

Such projection indeed exists. First, some simple linear algebra fact: if $V$ is an $m$-dimensional linear subspace of $R^p$ then there exists a coordinate subspace $W\cong R^m$ in $R^p$ such that the natural projection $\pi: R^p\to W$ satisfies $\pi(W)=V$. This is an immediate consequence of the fact that the row-rank of a matrix equals its column-rank.

Pick a point $p\in M$. The tangent space $T_pM$ is a $p$-dimensional linear subspace $V$ in $R^n$. Hence, as noted above, there is a coordinate subspace $W=R^m\subset R^n$ such that the restriction to $V$ of the natural 
projection $\pi: R^n\to W$ is surjective, i.e. has rank $m$. The [inverse mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Manifolds) (or the implicit function theorem if you prefer) then implies that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that the restriction of $\pi$ to $U$ is a diffeomorphism to its image and the image is an open subset of $R^m$. Let $S\subset M$ denote the subset consisting of points $q$ such that $d\pi: T_qM\to W$ has rank $<m$. By [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), $E=\pi(S)$ has Lebesgue measure zero in $W$: Sard's theorem applies in our case (even if $M$ is $C^1$-smooth) since $M$ and $W$ have the same dimension.  In other words, $E=\pi(S)$ has zero Lebesgue measure in $R^m$.

To conclude: The interior of $N$ has full (and positive!) measure in $N$, i.e. there exists a subset $E\subset N$ of zero measure such that $N-E$ is nonempty and open in $R^m$.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing out all the detail, I much appreciate it! Yes, I understood the proof, sorry for the delayed response! Upvoted!